# Select most recent non null row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres with timestamp and 6 columns (A,B,C,D,E,F) with values. Every 10 minutes new record is appended to this table, however for columns B, D, F actual value is fetched only every 30 minutes meaning that only every 3rd row is not null.

I would like to write a query that outputs most recent record per every column. The only thing that comes to my mind is to write 2 queries:

```
SELECT  A,C,E
    FROM data_prices 
    ORDER BY date_of_record DESC LIMIT 1



SELECT  B,D,F
        FROM data_prices 
        WHERE B is not null, D is not null, F is not null
        ORDER BY date_of_record DESC LIMIT 1
```

And then join the results into 1 table with 6 columns and 1 row. I don't know, however how to do that because in the documentation I found operations like `UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT` which append data rather than creating one wider table. Any ideas how to join these 2 selects into 1 table with 6 columns? Or maybe smarter way to get latest non NULL result per column in table?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Postgres does not support `lag(ignore nulls)`.

One method uses `first_value()`:

```
select date_of_record, a,
       first_value(b) over (order by (b is not null) desc, date_of_record desc) as last_b,
       c,
       first_value(d) over (order by (d is not null) desc, date_of_record desc) as last_d,
       e,
       first_value(f) over (order by (f is not null) desc, date_of_record desc) as last_f
from t
order by date_of_record desc
limit 1;
```